# Laravel Homestead 2.0 Adding New Sites

Tags: laravel, homestead

Homestead 2 is awesome, but I can't seem to get new sites to work without going through the following process.

1. I do `homestead edit` to setup the new site paths and domains etc
2. I edit `hosts` to set up the domain
3. I do `homestead halt` then `homestead up` to restart

This is when I think things should be working... but they don't. I have to run the additional step of

4. Running `vagrant global-status` getting the id and running `vagrant provision <id>`.

Everything works except running provision again wipes out all the databases! How do I add new sites without having to provision again?

Comment: `vagrant provision` on its own should work (from the homestead directory). You also shouldn't need to do `halt` or `up`. Your databases are likely getting wiped out because of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of step 3 use `vagrant provision` in your homestead directory (`~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/`).

As I know Taylor is already planning a "provision" flag, until that you can feel free to use vagrant commands.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
homestead halt && homestead up --provision
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `~/homestead/.Homestead.yaml` file, it contains a configuration for two apps, one with HHVM enabled and one with HHVM disabled(default in homestead).

Homestead will create the database for you in MySQL and PostgreSQL server, when running `homestead up`.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: jobs.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/jobs/public
    - map: messages.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/messages/web
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - jobs
    - messages

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

You can now run:
    $ `homestead up`

and then:
    $ `homestead ssh`

and then run byobu(for tmux):
    $ `byobu`

and cd into the project:
    $ `cd Projects/jobs`

and run composer:
    $ `composer update`