# How can I add a new site to Homestead 2.0 without wiping out the pre-existing databases?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I have been using Homestead 2.0 for awhile now for multiple projects and something frustrating keeps happening. Every time I add a new site it adds the new site and DB but wipes out the data in the existing databases.

I have tried the steps in [Laravel Homestead 2.0 Adding New Sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892861/laravel-homestead-2-0-adding-new-sites) but I get the same results each time.

So running "homestead halt && homestead up --provision" or "vagrant provision" gives me the same problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can do it manually (creating the db, the virtual server, etc) but it kills a lot of the purpose of using homestead.

Comment: I knew I could add the DB, I haven't looked into adding it to nginx manually. But you are right, that does defeat the purpose.

Comment: I can't test it right now (so I'm posting it as a comment and not as an answer), but try going to `~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/create-mysql.sh` and changing it to not drop your dbs. it should work.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/pull/177).

Comment: Excellent find Ravan. I added my two cents to it. It doesn't look like the call for the preserve option has yet to be accepted by the managing developers. So I will try to make a PR and add the ability myself.

Comment: @Ravan Go ahead and submit as an answer. I am going to give you the points for finding that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the mysql script that run everytime your homestead is provisioned.
Go to `~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/create-mysql.sh` and change it for your taste.

There was a pull-request to offer such funcionality, but it was closed with no explanation. Anyway, you can still copy the logic offered by it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DB=$1;

mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$DB\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
```

[Check it out here.](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/pull/177)

Comment: That works great. I may end up writing my own flag for it so that it doesn't wipe the databases. Maybe even add an identifier to the config file (Homestead.yaml) and then submitting a pull request to the project.